# Google Docs:NullPointerException in getActualParameterAtPosition called by parseAs

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to access Google Docs using google-api-java-client library. I'm using libraries listed below.

- google-api-client-1.4.1-beta.jar
- google-api-client-googleapis-1.4.1-beta.jar
- google-api-client-googleapis-extensions-andr
- guava-r09.jar

And I could get feed but could not parseAs, I got exception. My code is like;

```
HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
transport.defaultHeaders = headers;

headers.setApplicationName("hohoho-GoogleDocsTest/1.0");
headers.gdataVersion = "3";
headers.setGoogleLogin(authToken);

AtomParser parser = new AtomParser();
parser.namespaceDictionary = new XmlNamespaceDictionary();
transport.addParser(parser);

HttpRequest request = transport.buildGetRequest();
request.url = <GoogleUrl of "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full">
HttpResponse res = request.execute();
Feed feed = res.parseAs(Feed.class);    // <- got exception
```

And Stack trace is:

```
05-24 22:05:34.853: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6830): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-24 22:05:34.853: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6830):     at com.google.api.client.util.Types.getActualParameterAtPosition(Types.java:329)
05-24 22:05:34.853: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6830):     at com.google.api.client.util.Types.getIterableParameter(Types.java:309)
05-24 22:05:34.853: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6830):     at com.google.api.client.xml.Xml.parseElementInternal(Xml.java:417)
05-24 22:05:34.853: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6830):     at com.google.api.client.xml.Xml.parseElement(Xml.java:198)
05-24 22:05:34.853: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6830):     at com.google.api.client.http.xml.XmlHttpParser.parse(XmlHttpParser.java:72)
05-24 22:05:34.853: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6830):     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:298)
05-24 22:05:34.853: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6830):     at net.DailyTimer.test.model.Feed.executeGet(Feed.java:24)
```

I had no idea why it hit NullPointerException. For me, response looks good. Status is OK, code is 200, there are many items those must come from docs.

Please tell me what is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone viewed my question, I'm sorry that I gave up working with Google Docs in my app. First I thought I can upload/download any type of files to/from Google Docs as we can with Web browser. And [protocol guide](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) clearly stated how to do this. But unfortunately, it turned out that by using APIs, only [Google Apps Premier customer can do this](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/documents/faq.html#WhatKindOfFilesCanIUpload). So I can't fulfill what I want to do with Google Docs even if I can handle those APIs being helped by people here. I will stop working on Google Docs, so please forgive me that I can't be responsible for this question I made.